# How to identify that *ngFor loop has finished changes in markup?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have an array of companies getting from a service and binding that array data with the help of `*ngFor` directive.

Now, I want to show a whole page covered 'waiting..' till the data gets bind to the mark up.

Till the time, I tried this

```
GetCompanies()
{
//here is 'startWaitingModal()'
this._svc.GetCompanies().subscribe(ret => {}, error => {}, () => { //here is 'endWaitingModal()'});
}
```

and I understand that `endWaitingModal()` called immediately after service call completion not after binding completion, which makes sense. After that I found this solution angular life cycle hook, It is working fine.

```
ngDoCheck()
```

this hook gets triggered whenever there is change in the the component markup. It helps me but this solution is not up to the mark as per my knowledge, because it is working like a parent listener (listening continuously) and will look for any change in the markup and gets triggered which is not a right way to do it. It should work like element specific, I think. Please guide me.

Comment: Did you also check `ngAfterViewChecked` life cycle hook?

Comment: Post your html and more to show `*ngFor`

Comment: @AmitChigadani Yes, not worked out as a solution for this problem.

Comment: @WaelAbbas Brother, I think, I have explained the question pretty well. I mean, no need of HTML to paste here. Give a thought about it and explain me If I need. Thank you.

Comment: So if I've undestood right: show "waiting.." untill the subscription assign the data received. After that, loop&show the data with the *ngFor. Right?